# How to find logged / connected / current user in hive context object of spark sql?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

How to find logged / connected / current user in hive context object of spark sql?

Any sql query or Unix command  can be used.?

I tried with   ! Whoami; command in hive command prompt.  Is it a optimal solution

I need to get the logged user in sql query and wanted to insert it in table using spark sql

Answer (score -1):

In PySpark, use this

> > > sqlContext._sc.sparkUser()

or

> > > sqlContext.sql('select current_user()').show()